# Please make the feed customizable in the mobile app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I would like to have my Feed customizable, e.g. set priorities, favorite tags, filter (by time, active bounties, unanswered...)
Instead, it seems the very basics are missing! I am constantly annoyed by questions from Stack Exchange sites I don't care about.

Comment: Ops, I didn't mean to open a Meta post.. I guess this is how it works. Well, I suppose there are already duplicates of this requests: feel free to close this.

Comment: Luca, I'm not sure what you mean about duplicates.  If it's a dupe then somebody will find and mark it, but I don't see any obvious candidates and I don't see any deleted comments.  If you want to withdraw the question you can (currently) delete it, because it doesn't have any answers, but you could also [edit] to further expand on your request.

Comment: Check the tag for [android-app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app), the development is frozen.